# _.each throws error after npm update

Tags: node.js, mongoose, underscore.js, mongoose-schema, mongoose-plugins

Everything was running fine, before I run 'npm update' to push my code with latest libraries. Now I am getting error:

{ message: 'Method Map.prototype.has called on incompatible receiver #',
  stack: 'TypeError: Method Map.prototype.has called on incompatible receiver #\n    at Clone.has ()\n    at get (/Users/myproject/node_modules/kareem/index.js:418:11)\n    at Clone.Kareem.pre (/Users/myproject/node_modules/kareem/index.js:350:16)\n    at Clone.Schema.pre (/Users/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:1135:20)\n    at Schema.extend (/Users/myproject/node_modules/mongoose-schema-extend/index.js:73:15)\n    at Object.createSchema (/Users/myproject/framework/nDatabase/bin/system.js:341:89)\n    at /Users/myproject/framework/nDatabase/bin/system.js:384:24\n    at Array.forEach ()\n    at Object.resolveSchemaDependancy (/Users/myproject/framework/nDatabase/bin/system.js:356:25)\n    at /Users/myproject/framework/nDatabase/bin/system.js:406:24\n    at /Users/myproject/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4917:15\n    at baseForOwn (/Users/myproject/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3002:24)\n    at /Users/myproject/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4886:18\n    at Function.forEach (/Users/myproject/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9334:14)\n    at Object.traverseSchemas (/Users/myproject/framework/nDatabase/bin/system.js:401:11)\n    at Object.extractRawSchema (/Users/myproject/framework/nDatabase/bin/system.js:418:40)' }

Error indicate some issues with loadash library while using:

```
_.each({}, (object, name) =>{
  /////
});
```

Here is list of dependancies I am using :

```
"dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cron": "^1.3.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "java": "^0.9.1",
    "kafka-node": "^2.6.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "mocha": "^4.1.0",
    "mocha-suit": "^0.5.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.0-beta4",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.6",
    "mongoose-schema-extend": "0.2.0",
    "node-cache": "^4.2.0",
    "recursive-copy": "^2.0.8",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "should": "^13.2.1",
    "stompit": "^0.25.0",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "winston": "^2.4.3",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^3.2.1",
    "winston-elasticsearch": "^0.7.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "meow": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3"
}
```

Please help me to resolve this Issue.

Comment: Might I ask which version of NodeJS your machine are currently using?

Comment: Might need more details; AFAIK lodash itself works just fine.

Comment: @Node : v8.11.2

Comment: The issue I am facing here with 'mongoose-schema-extend' at : at Clone.Schema.pre (/Users/..../node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:1135:20)
    at Schema.extend (/Users/.../nodics/node_modules/mongoose-schema-extend/index.js:73:15)